# stop this slider from looping

Tags: jquery, loops, slider

I have this code and i want to prevent it from looping like example it has slide one slide two slide three, you must not be able to go to slide three from slide one and from slide one to slide three. Here is the jquery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

$('#checkbox').change(function(){
setInterval(function () {
    moveRight();
}, 3000);
});

var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

$('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

$('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

$('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: + slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: - slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

$('a.control_prev').click(function () {
    moveLeft();
});

$('a.control_next').click(function () {
    moveRight();
});

});
```

Thank you.

Comment: could you share the whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of no restrictions on `prependTo` and `appendTo` functions. comment them out.

Introduced a variable which will keep track of the slide you are currently on, and which will vary from 1 to no. of slides.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

$('#checkbox').change(function(){
setInterval(function () {
    moveRight();
}, 3000);
});

var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
  var current = 1;
var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

$('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

$('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

$('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: + slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: - slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

$('a.control_prev').click(function () {
  if(current>1){
    current--;
    moveLeft();
}
});

$('a.control_next').click(function () {
  if(current<slideCount){
    current++;
    moveRight();
  }
});

$(".slideButtons").click(function(){
   var clickedSlide =  $('.slideButtons').index(this)+1;
   $(".slideButtons").removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
   if (current>clickedSlide){
     var diff = current-clickedSlide;
     for(var l=0;l<diff;l++){
       current--;
       moveLeft();
     }
   }
   if (current<clickedSlide){
     var diff = clickedSlide-current;
     $(".slideButtons").removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass('active');
     for(var l=0;l<diff;l++){
       current++;
       moveRight();
     }
   }
});
});
```

```css
html {
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  background: #58DDAF;
  color: #2a2a2a;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}

a.control_prev, a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev:hover, a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

a.control_next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.slideButtons.active{
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Incredibly Basic Slider</h1>
<button class="slideButtons active">Slide 1</button>
<button class="slideButtons">Slide 2</button>
<button class="slideButtons">Slide 3</button>
<button class="slideButtons">Slide 4</button>
<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">></a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev"><</a>
  <ul>
    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li>SLIDE 3</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
  </ul>  
</div>

<div class="slider_option">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
  <label for="checkbox">Autoplay Slider</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your version but i didn't work can you try on this pen instead? https://codepen.io/doodlemarks/pen/aFcly

Comment: any idea on how to add the navigation links to it? thank you

Comment: sorry, I don,t get your question. are you saying like `previous` and `next`

Comment: i mean like this <nav class="slider-nav">
 <a href="#slide-0" class="active">Slide 0</a> 
  <a href="#slide-1">Slide 1</a> 
  <a href="#slide-2">Slide 2</a> 
    <a href="#slide-3">Slide 3</a> 
  </div> 
when you click on it it takes you to the slide

Comment: It's done. you can replace the buttons with `a` tags, I just used them beacause it's easy. Also please do accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: one more thing please how to add the class .active to the current button corresponding to the slide being showed